# Css nav failed to fit after page was resized

Tags: css

the nav seam to work perfectly on a full page browser but when resized it uses the windows size as width

this is what the nav looks like in a full page
 [image]

And this is how it turn after browser windows is resized
[image]

here is the [current code](http://jsfiddle.net/4SVXt/866/) am using try scroll through the result box

```
.
```

Comment: post your code here or your question will get closed. You were warned about this when you posted your question. That's why you entered a single dot in a code block

Comment: It's breaking because you set the width of the inner divs `top-nav`, `middle-nav` and `last-nav` to fixed 1000px. Therefore while the blue one will follow the width % you gave, the inner ones are overflowing because of the fixed width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've two options. Either you can make the whole navigation bar responsive by replacing the two instances of `width: 1000px` with `width: 100%` in the CSS, like this (you will need to style the navigation links separately then using `@media-queries` for devices with a smaller screen):

```css
#navs{
 position: relative;
 width:100%;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
 -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
 box-shadow:         0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
 z-index:10000;
 
}

#navs > .top-nav{
 position:relative;
 background:#555;
 height:20px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #333;
 
}
#navs > .top-nav > .top-nav-content{
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 color:#ddd;
 font-size:12px;
 text-align: right;
 
 

}
#navs > .middle-nav{
 position:relative;
 background:#0b99d0 url('../img/middle-nav-bg.png');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 height:50px; width:100%;
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 min-width: 1100;
 
}
#navs > .middle-nav > .logo-container{
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 height:50px;
 
}
.logo, .usr-login{
 display:inline-block; 
}
#navs > .middle-nav > .logo-container >  .logo{
 background:url('../img/logo.png');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:contain;
 background-position: right bottom;
 text-shadow:1px 1px #023f52;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width:215px;height:50px;
 font-size:28px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#eee;
 
}
.body-holder{
 width:1120px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.usr-login{
 float:right;
 margin-top:0px;
 color:#eee;
 margin-right:10%;
 margin-top:13px;
 
}

#navs > .last-nav{
 width:100%;
    background:#fff;
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-size:contain;
 padding-top:4px;
}
#navs > .last-nav > .last-nav-content{
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 height:44px;

}
.nav-menu-wrap, .search-menu-wrap{
 height:40px;
 display: inline-block;

}
.nav-menu-wrap {
 width:29%;height:40px;
 position:relative;

}
.search-menu-wrap{
 width:70%;height:40px;
 position: relative;
 top:3px;
 

}
.nav-menu-wrap > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 top:-3px;
 float:right;
}

.nav-menu-wrap > ul li {
    float: left;
 border-left:1px solid #e9e9e9;
 border-right:1px solid #fff;
 padding:12px 4px;
}
.nav-menu-wrap > ul li:first-child {
 border-left:1px solid #e9e9e9;
}
.nav-menu-wrap > ul li:last-child {
 border-right:1px solid #e9e9e9;
}

.nav-menu-wrap > ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #fff;
 text-align:center;
 color:#0694c6;
 outline:none;
}
.nav-menu-wrap > ul li a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
}
.nav-login ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;  
  font-family: Optima, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; 
}
.nav-login li {
  float: left;          
}
.nav-login #login {
  border-right:0;
}
.nav-login #login-trigger,
.nav-login #signup a { 
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:14px; 
}
.drp-icon{
 font-size:10px;
}
.kp-me-lin{
 font-weight:100;
}
.nav-login #signup a {
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.nav-login #login-trigger {
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  outline: 0;
  outline-style:none;
  outline-width:0;
}
.nav-login #login-trigger:hover,
.nav-login #login .active,
.nav-login #signup a:hover {
 color:#ddd;
 text-shadow:1px 1px #004b63;
 outline: 0;
    outline-style:none;
    outline-width:0;
}
.nav-login #login-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;    
  background: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);  
  padding: 15px;
  border:1px solid #efefef;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
  color:#444;
  border-radius:4px;
}
.nav-login li #login-content {
  right: 0;
  width: 270px;  
}
#inputs input {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  width: 238px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc inset;
}
```

```html
<body style="background:#efefef;">
<div id="navs">
<div class="top-nav">
<div class="top-nav-content">Number</div> </div>
<div class="middle-nav">
<div class="logo-container"><div class="logo">Head</div><div class="usr-login">


<div class="nav-login">
  <ul>
    <li id="login">
      <a id="login-trigger" href="#">
        Login <b class="drp-icon">▼</b>
      </a>
      <div id="login-content">
        <form>
          <fieldset id="inputs">
            <input id="usercath" type="email" cath="Email" placeholder="Your email address" required>   
            <input id="password" type="password" cath="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
            <label class="kp-me-lin"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Keep me signed in</label>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
        
      </div>                     
    </li>
    <li id="signup">
      <a href="">Register</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div></div>
</div></div>
<div class="last-nav"><div class="last-nav-content">
<div class="search-menu-wrap">
 <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
    <div class="preview">
        </select>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /btn-group -->
  
</div>
 </div>
 <div class="nav-menu-wrap">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Deals</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Help</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="body-holder">
```

Or you can make the whole navigation bar static, i.e. it's width will be fixed regardless of the screen size you view it on, like this:

```css
#navs{
 position: relative;
 width:1200px;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
 -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
 box-shadow:         0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
 z-index:10000;
 
}

#navs > .top-nav{
 position:relative;
 background:#555;
 height:20px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #333;
 
}
#navs > .top-nav > .top-nav-content{
 width:1200px;
 margin:0 auto;
 color:#ddd;
 font-size:12px;
 text-align: right;
 
 

}
#navs > .middle-nav{
 position:relative;
 background:#0b99d0 url('../img/middle-nav-bg.png');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 height:50px; width:1200px;
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 min-width: 1100;
 
}
#navs > .middle-nav > .logo-container{
 width:1200px;
 margin:0 auto;
 height:50px;
 
}
.logo, .usr-login{
 display:inline-block; 
}
#navs > .middle-nav > .logo-container >  .logo{
 background:url('../img/logo.png');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:contain;
 background-position: right bottom;
 text-shadow:1px 1px #023f52;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width:215px;height:50px;
 font-size:28px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#eee;
 
}
.body-holder{
 width:1120px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.usr-login{
 float:right;
 margin-top:0px;
 color:#eee;
 margin-right:10%;
 margin-top:13px;
 
}

#navs > .last-nav{
 width:1200px;
    background:#fff;
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-size:contain;
 padding-top:4px;
}
#navs > .last-nav > .last-nav-content{
 width:1200px;
 margin:0 auto;
 height:44px;

}
.nav-menu-wrap, .search-menu-wrap{
 height:40px;
 display: inline-block;

}
.nav-menu-wrap {
 width:29%;height:40px;
 position:relative;

}
.search-menu-wrap{
 width:70%;height:40px;
 position: relative;
 top:3px;
 

}
.nav-menu-wrap > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 top:-3px;
 float:right;
}

.nav-menu-wrap > ul li {
    float: left;
 border-left:1px solid #e9e9e9;
 border-right:1px solid #fff;
 padding:12px 4px;
}
.nav-menu-wrap > ul li:first-child {
 border-left:1px solid #e9e9e9;
}
.nav-menu-wrap > ul li:last-child {
 border-right:1px solid #e9e9e9;
}

.nav-menu-wrap > ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #fff;
 text-align:center;
 color:#0694c6;
 outline:none;
}
.nav-menu-wrap > ul li a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
}
.nav-login ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;  
  font-family: Optima, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Candara, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif; 
}
.nav-login li {
  float: left;          
}
.nav-login #login {
  border-right:0;
}
.nav-login #login-trigger,
.nav-login #signup a { 
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:14px; 
}
.drp-icon{
 font-size:10px;
}
.kp-me-lin{
 font-weight:100;
}
.nav-login #signup a {
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.nav-login #login-trigger {
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  outline: 0;
  outline-style:none;
  outline-width:0;
}
.nav-login #login-trigger:hover,
.nav-login #login .active,
.nav-login #signup a:hover {
 color:#ddd;
 text-shadow:1px 1px #004b63;
 outline: 0;
    outline-style:none;
    outline-width:0;
}
.nav-login #login-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;    
  background: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  padding: 15px;
  border:1px solid #efefef;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
  color:#444;
  border-radius:4px;
}
.nav-login li #login-content {
  right: 0;
  width: 270px;  
}
#inputs input {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  width: 238px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc inset;
}
```

```html
<body style="background:#efefef;">
<div id="navs">
<div class="top-nav">
<div class="top-nav-content">Number</div> </div>
<div class="middle-nav">
<div class="logo-container"><div class="logo">Head</div><div class="usr-login">


<div class="nav-login">
  <ul>
    <li id="login">
      <a id="login-trigger" href="#">
        Login <b class="drp-icon">▼</b>
      </a>
      <div id="login-content">
        <form>
          <fieldset id="inputs">
            <input id="usercath" type="email" cath="Email" placeholder="Your email address" required>   
            <input id="password" type="password" cath="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
            <label class="kp-me-lin"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Keep me signed in</label>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
        
      </div>                     
    </li>
    <li id="signup">
      <a href="">Register</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div></div>
</div></div>
<div class="last-nav"><div class="last-nav-content">
<div class="search-menu-wrap">
 <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
    <div class="preview">
        </select>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /btn-group -->
  
</div>
 </div>
 <div class="nav-menu-wrap">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Deals</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Help</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="body-holder">
```